# winsock : bluetooth address conversion from string

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++, bluetooth, winsock

I am using winsock since a few days.

I wish to use bluetooth for my project and I have to do the coding using winsock.

We can convert a string to an IPV4 address using inet_addr() function.
I wish to convert a string to BT_ADDR type.

How can I do it? Is there any function for this?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at you MSDN thread! [MSDN Thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8e5487bf-d3b4-49c8-8410-bf915495fca1/winsock-bluetooth-address-conversion-from-string?forum=ApplicationInsights)